# Problem with composite letters in section labels

Tags: unicode, letters

Although there are some advices that deal with the warning message:

> Composite letter `\textasciicaron+c'not defined in PD1 encoding

See here, for example:
[Problem with UTF-8 in meta data](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150012/problem-with-utf-8-in-meta-data/150013)
It seems that I cannot get rid of these warnings if letters appear in section (subsection) labels (`\section{Example: \v{s}}`). Can anyone give me some advice?

My header contains:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english,serbian]{babel}
\usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

And I also tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english,serbian]{babel}
\usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

Many thanks! PM

===========================================================

**MINIMAL EXAMPLE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english,serbian]{babel}
\usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
%
\xdefinecolor{myStructureColor}{RGB}{51,158,51}
\xdefinecolor{myAlertedColor}{RGB}{255,51,51}
\xdefinecolor{myTextColor}{RGB}{60,60,60}
\xdefinecolor{midGrey}{RGB}{180,180,180}
\xdefinecolor{lightGrey}{RGB}{225,225,225}
%
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=myTextColor}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=myStructureColor}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=myAlertedColor}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=myAlertedColor}
%
\setbeamerfont{structure}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{shape=\scshape}
%
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.06in]{backbulls/bulettA}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.05in]{backbulls/bulettB}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.05in]{backbulls/bulettC}}
%
\AtBeginSection[]
{\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Sadr\v zaj}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}}
%
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
%
\title{Slo\v zeni linearni modeli}
\date{\tiny{februar 2014. godine}}
%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{spacing}{2}
\titlepage
\end{spacing}
\end{frame}

\section{Ve\v zba}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Works}
previous section label works fine...
\end{frame}

\section{\v Cinjenica}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Does not work}
previous section label does not work...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\vspace*{4\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
    {\LARGE{K~~~R~~~A~~~J}}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please post a *complete*, minimal document allowing us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have added minimal example above...

Answer (score 5):

Add the `unicode` option to `hyperref` (with this option the range of supported letters is larger).

```
\documentclass[12pt,hyperref={unicode}]{beamer}
\usepackage[english,serbian]{babel}
\usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=0.95]{opensans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
%
\xdefinecolor{myStructureColor}{RGB}{51,158,51}
\xdefinecolor{myAlertedColor}{RGB}{255,51,51}
\xdefinecolor{myTextColor}{RGB}{60,60,60}
\xdefinecolor{midGrey}{RGB}{180,180,180}
\xdefinecolor{lightGrey}{RGB}{225,225,225}
%
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=myTextColor}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=myStructureColor}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=myAlertedColor}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=myAlertedColor}
%
\setbeamerfont{structure}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{shape=\scshape}
%
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.06in]{backbulls/bulettA}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.05in]{backbulls/bulettB}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.05in]{backbulls/bulettC}}
%
\AtBeginSection[]
{\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Sadr\v zaj}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}}
%
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
%
\title{Slo\v zeni linearni modeli}
\date{\tiny{februar 2014. godine}}
%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{spacing}{2}
\titlepage
\end{spacing}
\end{frame}

\section{Ve\v zba}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Works}
previous section label works fine...
\end{frame}

\section{\v Cinjenica}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Does not work}
previous section label does not work...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\vspace*{4\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
    {\LARGE{K~~~R~~~A~~~J}}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Line

```
\documentclass[12pt,hyperref={unicode}]{beamer}
```

does not work for me,

I solve my problem with

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

insted of

```
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Well, that is specific for `beamer`; with other classes, you load `hyperref` as you state.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Actualy, my case was `book`, and
`\documentclass[12pt,hyperref={unicode}]{book}`
sure doesn't work.